# Replication not working in alfresco 4.1.5 EE

Tags: replication, alfresco

I am trying to replicate a folder from Server A to Server B.
I am getting the following exception:

```
org.alfresco.service.cmr.replication.ReplicationServiceException: 11290356 Error executing transfer - 11290354 Unable to start a transfer
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:241)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:799)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:710)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.AsynchronousActionExecutionQueueImpl$ActionExecutionWrapper$1$1.execute(AsynchronousActionExecutionQueueImpl.java:405)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:259)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.AsynchronousActionExecutionQueueImpl$ActionExecutionWrapper$1.doWork(AsynchronousActionExecutionQueueImpl.java:414)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.AsynchronousActionExecutionQueueImpl$ActionExecutionWrapper.run(AsynchronousActionExecutionQueueImpl.java:417)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.transfer.TransferException: 11290354 Unable to start a transfer
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.alfresco.util.json.ExceptionJsonSerializer.deserialize(ExceptionJsonSerializer.java:92)
    at org.alfresco.util.json.ExceptionJsonSerializer.deserialize(ExceptionJsonSerializer.java:34)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transfer.HttpClientTransmitterImpl.rehydrateError(HttpClientTransmitterImpl.java:738)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transfer.HttpClientTransmitterImpl.checkResponseStatus(HttpClientTransmitterImpl.java:186)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transfer.HttpClientTransmitterImpl.begin(HttpClientTransmitterImpl.java:275)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transfer.TransferServiceImpl2.transferImpl(TransferServiceImpl2.java:596)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transfer.TransferServiceImpl2.transfer(TransferServiceImpl2.java:539)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transfer.TransferServiceImpl2.transfer(TransferServiceImpl2.java:514)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor$1.execute(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor.invoke(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy125.transfer(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I am not an expert in that area, but most likely more details are required: What have you tried? What does the log says?

Comment: I am getting above exception in log file while I am running replication job. Any help please?

Comment: Since you're running the Alfresco Enterprise version, you'd be much much better off giving Alfresco Support a call - they know this stuff inside out!

Comment: Do you have enabled the ReplicationService adding the following property in the alfresco-global.properties? replication.enabled=true. You can also do the same using JMX without restarting Alfresco

Comment: I have already set all replication configuration properties in alfresco-global.properties file.